# Alternative to std::inner_product algorithm?

Tags: c++, std

I know the `std::inner_product` algorithm will have problems if you're dealing with two arrays of different sizes. Is there another standard library algorithm that can work with arrays of different sizes, e.g. by automatically using the smaller of the two array sizes?

Comment: Don't know, but it would not be difficult to implement.

Comment: How about selecting the smaller size yourself, just with a `if` before the function call?

Comment: @deviantfan Figuring out the sizes of the ranges can be quite inefficient if you don't have RandomAccessIterators, and impossible if you have InputIterators.

Comment: @Praetorian: He mentioned "arrays". So any of these iterators should be no problem.

Comment: @deviantfan Agreed, but surely you also agree that in this case, it'd be wise to think beyond "I need this to work for arrays right now".

Answer (score 3):

Not too hard to implement one.

```
template <class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2, class T>
   T inner_product (InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
                    InputIterator2 first2, InputIterator2 last2, T init)
{
   for ( ; first1 != last1 && first2 != last2; ++first1, ++first2 )
   {
      init += (*first1)*(*first2);
   }
   return init;
}
```

Comment: I think you should return a triple of the computed value and the two final iterators `first1`, `first2` (because this is information that may be impossible or expensive to compute, e.g. for output or not-RandomAccess iterators).

Comment: Here's what I ended up doing: double SomeClass::SomeFunction( std::vector< double >&vector1 )   { if (vector1.size() < vector2.size()) { return std::inner_product(vector1.begin(), vector2.end(), vector2.begin(), 0.0); } else { return std::inner_product(vector2.begin(), vector2.end(), vector1.begin(), 0.0); } }

Comment: @R Sahu Okay, thanks.  Just curious as to whether your code was better (or more efficient) than mine.  Maybe I'm just splitting hairs.